# syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']' in config.php

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml

```
$dbhost = "10.21.47.198"; 
$dbuser = "xxxxx"; 
$dbpass = "xxxxx"; 
$dbname = "xxxxxx"; 
$prefix = "art_"; // you can change this prefix but not necessary 
$cdomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='xxxxxxxxx' ? '' : ".$_SERVER[xxxxxxxxxxx]"; //.yoursite.com $date_format = "F d, Y"; 
$admin_email = "contact@seoinabook.com";
```

the above code is part of an article publisher script. It is the next line after the standard database info,

(db=database name, username= username, etc.)

It seems to install okay, but when I try to go to the home page or admin page this kicks in. What does it mean by server name and then server? I thought they were the same unless server name is like the public_html.

this is the error I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']' in /home2/seobook/public_html/articlepublish/config.php on line 28
```

Comment: I don't understand : is seoinabook.com a valid key for $_SERVER array?

Comment: No it is not : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: sorry, I was not clear, the script is as follows:
$dbhost = "10.21.47.198";
 $dbuser = "xxxxx";
 $dbpass = "xxxxx";
 $dbname = "xxxxxx";
 $prefix = "art_"; // you can change this prefix but not necessary

 $cdomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='xxxxxxxxx' ? '' : ".$_SERVER[xxxxxxxxxxx]";//.yoursite.com
 $date_format = "F d, Y";
 $admin_email = "contact@seoinabook.com";

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the dot in `$_SERVER[seoinabook.com]`. Try quoting the key, `$_SERVER['seoinabook.com']`.

Comment: Ewan your answer is wrong. 'seoinabook.com' is not a key in the $_SERVER array.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right code will be:

```
## set domain prefix if current domain is not main
$cdomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='seoinabook.com' ? '' : "seoinabook.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me that the code should look like this...

$cdomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='seoinabook.com' ? '' : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

it says that $cdomain should equal '' if the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] equals 'seoinabook.com' else it will equal $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Comment: ls:Table 'seobook_oneadmin.art_styles' doesn't exist
Now it says this after wh at seems to be a good install